# BeautifulSoup parser appends semicolons to naked ampersands, mangling URLs?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some site in python that has links in it to other sites, but in plain text, not in "a" tag. Using BeautifulSoup I get the wrong answer. Consider this code:

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = """<html>
            <head>
              <title>Test html</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <div>
                example.com/a.php?b=2&c=15
              </div>
            </body>
          </html>"""

parsed = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
print parsed
```

when I run the above code I get the following output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      example.com/a.php?b=2&c;=15
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice the link in the "div" and the part b=2&c;=15. It's different from the original HTML. Why is BeautifulSoup messing with the links in such a way. Is it trying to automagically create HTML entites? How to prevent this?

Comment: Suggest you change title to _'BeautifulSoup parser appends semicolons to naked ampersands, mangling URLs'_

Answer (score 7):

Apparently BS has an underdocumented [issue parsing ampersands inside URL](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup/browse_thread/thread/f591f8c795afdd61/ea9b73b423c1032f?lnk=gst&q=semicolon#), I just searched their discussion forum for 'semicolon'. According to that discussion from 2009, naked `&` is strictly not valid and must be replaced by `&amp;` although browsers accept this so it seems waay pedantic.

I agree this parsing behavior is bogus, and you should contact their list to ask them to at least document this better as a known issue, and fix it in future.

**Workaround:** Anyway, your workaround will most likely be `re.sub(...)` to capture and expand `&` -> `&amp;` only inside URLs. Possibly you need a reverse function to compress them in the output. You'll need a fancier regex to capture only ampersands inside URLs, but anyway:

```
# Minimal string to tickle this
#html = "<html>example.com/a.php?b=2&c=15&d=42</html>"
html = "<html>example.com/a.php?b=2&c=15&amp;d=29&e=42</html>"

html = re.sub(r'&(?!amp;)', r'&amp;', html)

parsed = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print parsed.text.encode('utf-8')
'example.com/a.php?b=2&amp;c=15'

>>> re.sub(r'&amp;', r'&', parsed.text.encode('utf-8'))
'example.com/a.php?b=2&c=15'
```

There may be other more BS-thonic approaches.
You may want to help test the 4.0 beta.

Comment: The problem with this is if other entities are used; e.g. if I have `&trade;`, or an already-escaped `&amp;`, they will be displayed as `&trade;` and `&amp;` rather than `™` or `&`. Ideally you want a negative lookahead assertion to check that it's not a valid entity.

Comment: @Chris: good point, I added the negative lookahead assertion. (The regex still needs code to only match URLs though.)

Comment: I had the same thought as @ChrisMorgan. I checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references to find that entities can be between 2 and 8 chars so I buffered it to 9 in my test: `re.sub(r'&(?![a-zA-Z0-9]{2,9};)', r'&amp;', html)`

Comment: @RichardBronosky: that may cope with plain HTML, but if you go dealing with any XML that length assertion certainly will not hold (nor for that matter will the assertion of the potential characters). For example, in Firefox's XUL you regularly get entities (they're used for translation) which are rather long, e.g. `robots.pagetitle` in about:robots.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, good to know. I'll try to be cautious of that if ever I am dealing with non-html. Thanks.